# Data from partial view not posting

Tags: c#, partial-views, razor-pages, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have the following page :

```
<form method="post">
<hr />
<h4>Alert</h4>
<div class="card-overview">
    <div class="card-columns">
        <partial name="_Alert" model="Model.Details.AlertPageModel" />
    </div>
</div>
```

My partial view looks as follows:

```
@model AlertPageModel
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
    @Html.TextBox("AlertPageModel.AlertDate", Model.AlertDate)
    @Html.TextBox("AlertPageModel.Message", Model.Message)
</div>
```

This results in my partial view as follows:

```
<input id="AlertPageModel_Message" name="AlertPageModel.Message" type="text" value="">
<input id="AlertPageModel_AlertDate" name="AlertPageModel.AlertDate" type="text" value="24/06/2019 10:23:12">
```

Now when I do a post of the page, my AlerPageModel remains empty.
I thought it would get filled this way.
What am I missing?

Comment: Make your model to include properties of both of your views, then it will map correctly, and you can filter which values you are looking for.

Comment: @mahlatse: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please explain?

Comment: The idea is , if you have model A,B,C,D as partial models inside a view, their respective models all get posted back with the parent model form, so you just need to include the properties as part of the mainview model and filter server side. ( or just use a simple js sript to change your formaction and post

Comment: @mahlatse: I'm sorry but I still don't understand what you mean. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the element is mapped to the property in the model when form is posted back. It looks like the names are not correct. You will need to specify the TextBox name like following so that it is posted in the property :

```
@Html.TextBox("Details.AlertPageModel.AlertDate", Model.AlertDate)
@Html.TextBox("Details.AlertPageModel.AlertPageModel.Message", Model.Message)
```

As your model `AlertPageModel` is a property of `Details` property in your main Model class we need to specify the name correctly so that it gets mapped to proper Model object and Model Binder can figure out that this value needs to be mapped on which particular property in the Model object.

Alternatively you can use `EditorFor` and define an editor template instead of partial which takes care of prefixing the proper name so that it is properly binded in the form post. You may read more about this at following post:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079909/ASP-NET-MVC-Partial-Views-with-Partial-Models

Hope it makes sense.